# Does not recognize android command in path

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, sdk, path

I'm triying to build my first cordova project, when I'm inside the project folder i tip: 
sudo cordova build android 
and I get the following error:

```
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/veritopsecret/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

when I do echo $PATH I get:

```
veritopsecret@veritopsecret-SATELLITE-PRO-C50-A-1HQ:~/hello$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/veritopsecret/Escriptori/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/veritopsecret/Escriptori/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

I have also modified .profile file, but it stills say that it hasn't android command in the PATH. However, if I just write android, it opens the android sdk manager. Help please!!

Comment: have you installed the android sdk tools and platform tools using the SDK manager?

Comment: Yes, I did! I have version 19. Does it matter?

Comment: 19 is perfect, it's the one used by default by cordova. In your profile folder, you should have a .cordova folder, and somewhere in there you should find a script named check_reqs script (something like .cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/check_reqs). If you run it, you may get a more acurate error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I re-read your question, I see you run `sudo cordova build android`

I think the issue you have is that you define ANDROID_HOME and add the android tools to the path of your user but then you use sudo to run the build.

sudo runs with elevated privileges using a user which is not your user profile that you are logged with, so the path and ANDROID_HOME are not set. (maybe try `sudo echo $PATH` to be sure of that).

So if you really wanted to use sudo to build, you would need either to define the vars for the sudo user or use instead sudo -E (see this page for more details : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Environment_variables)

But actually, you should be using sudo only when installing cordova, not when using the CLI.

So, just run `cordova build android` and everything should be fine.

Comment: It worked! Finally I realized that I had to give permisson to assets folder and it worked without sudo. Thank you very much!